# How does Java calculate font line spacing? (Calculate spacing between 2 lines in Times New Roman)

Tags: java, fonts, jtextarea, spacing

So I'm creating an extremely variable interface where even the font almost has to be variable (just trust me, I need it so it works on every resolution)
But obviously, there're multiple lines if text, where there is space between the separate lines.

After some trying out I found that the space between a font isn't static (for example, 2 pixels), so it has to be a percentage of the full font (for example, percentage is 25% and the font size is 40 pixels, than the spacing is 10 pixels) or some sort of formula.

After some search work I couldn't find anything about the spacing of a font, so I thought it was Java specific.
I doubt this, though. Since Java doesn't have a method where you can change this spacing (as far as I could find).

So my question is, is there any way to either change or get to know the spacing between 2 lines of Times New Roman text?

The biggest problem is that I need to know this to CREATE the font...
In case needed the formula:
fontSize = (myTextArea.getHeight()-([fontAscend]+[fontDescent])*21)/22

P.S. I'm using a JTextArea and prefer not to use a JEditorPane

Comment: Take a look at [Working with Text APIs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/index.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you're after?

```
myTextArea.getFontMetrics().getHeight()
```

`getFontMetrics` is a [method on JComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getFontMetrics%28java.awt.Font%29) which gives you a `FontMetrics` object that has a [`getHeight()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html#getHeight%28%29).

Comment: If I'm right that gives only the height of the font? (e.g. 14p) Instead of the spacing between the lines?

Comment: It includes the value of `getLeading()` which is the space between the lines, so it should do the right thing.

Comment: Problem: I need to use this spacing to calculate the font size itself, The FontMetrics class constructor requires a Font which requires a font size.

Answer (score 0):

The spacing between lines depends on whether the line of text has descenders or not.

Read the introduction to the [FontMetrics class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) for everything you never wanted to know about ascent and descent.

Comment: Problem: I need to use this spacing to calculate the font size itself, The FontMetrics class constructor requires a Font which requires a font size.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that with my specific problem (where I have to create a font and I need that same font to be able to create it) the only options are to either use a JEditorPane and use CSS to set the spacing to a specific value which I can use in my formula or to use algebra to get the right value.